# Android isn't recognizing different styles among different style files

Tags: android, styles

I currently have the application set-up fairly responsively across all layouts within

```
res/values/style.xml
```

but I need to target some layouts within XHDPI.

I have a second style.xml

```
res/values-xhdpi/style.xml
```

dedicated to this. I am seeing the style modifications within xhdpi devices. Unfortunately, these changes are also being seen within my hdpi devices. Is there any additional set-up required?

Answer (score 2):

The density qualifier is the one exception where Android might prefer the "higher" qualifier instead of the next "lower" one.

See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch

> Exception: If the qualifier in question is screen pixel density,
>   Android selects the option that most closely matches the device screen
>   density. In general, Android prefers scaling down a larger original
>   image to scaling up a smaller original image. See Supporting Multiple
>   Screens.

And here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support

> However, when the system is looking for a density-specific resource
>   and does not find it in the density-specific directory, it won't
>   always use the default resources. The system may instead use one of
>   the other density-specific resources in order to provide better
>   results when scaling. For example, when looking for a low-density
>   resource and it is not available, the system prefers to scale-down the
>   high-density version of the resource, because the system can easily
>   scale a high-density resource down to low-density by a factor of 0.5,
>   with fewer artifacts, compared to scaling a medium-density resource by
>   a factor of 0.75.

So what you need to do it copy your style.xml into values-hdpi as well.

Comment: Yep, this. Which truly *sucks* sometimes when you want to make just one difference for a specific density (`tvdpi`, anyone?)

Comment: Thanks for the documentation and explanation. Being used to responsive web design, I assumed the system would read the values/style.xml, then check density-specific resources for updates in style.